# Monodevelop неправильно отображает кодировку windows-1251

Tags: c#, кодировка, monodevelop

Редактор monodevelpo не отображает кодировку windows-1251. Не отображается, даже если при открытии файла указать кодировку 1251

Версия monodevelop 7.8.4 (build 2)

файл открывается в кодировке ISO 8859-1

[image: пример]

Comment: Это скорее не в кодировке проблема, в том, что используемый шрифт не поддерживает кириллицу. И вообще, используйте utf-8 как кодировку для хранения текстов или кода.

Comment: Дело не в шрифте, в monodevelop использую hack и ubuntu шрифты, а они поддерживает кириллицу

Comment: Выглядит это просто точно так, как я написал. Отправьте на покой 1251 и пробуйте перекодироваться и работать в utf-8.

Comment: Но ведь при переводе на utf-8 тест в комментариях потеряется, а кода в проекте накопилось не мало

Comment: Так вы перекодируйте все файлы с кодом в utf-8. Всё сохранится. Попробуйте на одном файле, затем автоматизируйте. 1251 - это прошлый век времен Windows XP. Уже давно мало что поддерживает и нормально работает с этой кодировкой, чему собственно вы свидетелем и стали, мне так кажется.

Comment: Можно, конечно, но в проекте более 2000 cs-файлов с которым параллельно работают в Windows. Конвертировать все файлы, конечно, можно, но, с другой стороны, хочется, заставить работать заявленную в MonoDevelop функциональность. (Надо было написать выше, например в kate и kwrite все хорошо открываетя)

Comment: Windows продолжит нормально работать с этими файлами в utf-8, а чтобы перекодировать, можно на том же шарпе написать за полчаса рекурсивный перекодировщик. Ну и наверняка кто-то с таким вопросом изменения кодировки `.cs` файлов сталкивался, наверняка можно поискать, вдруг та же студия умеет такое из-коробки, а может git это умеет, и т.д. Кстати, а от руки вы комменты на русском можете писать в том же файле, что на скриншоте например?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, так и сделаю, если не разберусь